# Ideas for a Javascript library release feed?

Tags: javascript, web

Anyone know of a website that lists releases for the major JS libraries?

I'm looking for something that will alert me of a new release and supply a link to download it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just launched a site for this, though there's still some IE issues to be ironed out.

http://libtracker.com/

Fill out the "Suggest a Library" form and I'll get onto adding anything you need. Email notifications will be added soon.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [**Google's API**](http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/), no worries about new versions anymore.

If you want to include the latest stable version of jQuery:

```
google.load("jquery", "1");
```

is enough.

Comment: That will only load the latest version in that subset - it won't load version 2.x.x only 1.x.x